# No Code Inspection tab in TeamCity builds (FindBugs)

Tags: java, continuous-integration, teamcity, findbugs, teamcity-8.0

Recently we tried to include code analyzing tool in our Java builds - FindBugs. 
[image: Build Feature - XML report processing]

But for some reason, after teamcity build finished and FB xml files parsed there is no Code Inspection tab on build page.

[image: log]

There is no errors in logs and i can't find a way to make this tab appear in a forced manner.

[image: no tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Code Inspection tab appeared after TeamCity reboot and checking FB in bugged targets. So, tab may not be visible if there is no bugs (and sometimes you need to restart TC).